# How can i connect to server by telnet with busytbox

Tags: telnet, busybox

I use telnet in busybox and can log in to the server normally most of the time, but sometimes I encounter a strange bug. This is an occasional bug. The specific situation is that after entering the correct username and password, it will get stuck